# XSLT and XML does not match

Tags: xml, xslt, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I have an XML on which I am doing an XSLT transformation. The XSLT I am receiving from some other source, so I have no control over it. The problem occurs when there is a slight difference between the XSLT and XML. For example my XML looks initially like this:

```
<a>
   <b></b>
   <c></c>
</a>
```

Later my XML changes to something like this:

```
<a>
   <b>
      <c></c>
   </b>
</a>
```

So in the second case, the XSLT transformation throws heap space exception. 
Is there any way I can validate my XSLT against the XML? I want to check if the XSLT corresponds to the correct XML.
Can someone tell me how can I avoid this outOfMemory Exception and even if I get this exception, how can I prevent this application to consume all the JVM heap memory?

Comment: Without seeing your XSLT and some real input XML it is impossible to tell what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a DTD or XML Schema? Then you can validate the transformation output. As for validation of the transformation itself without running it, that seems to run afoul of the incompleteness theorem.

As for preventing the transformation to eat up all your memory, the only reliable way to prevent this is sandboxing it into a separate process with controlled memory constraints.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.